# Stop PHP STRPOS function from ignoring zeros

Tags: php

I am creating a script that will find files from an input file (right now I am working on a jpg).

I use common file headers/trailers/structure to find the data that needs to be extracted. I use STRPOS to find these commonalities and find the parts of the file that need to be copied from the rest of the data etc etc.

Anyways, I am running into an issue, STRPOS is supposed to be looking for the string, "FFD9"... however it is finding it in incorrect positions!

For example, my hex in my JPG file looks as such,

[image: Wrong String!]

See the FF and the D9 on each side of the zero? STRPOS seems to be ignoring that 00 in-between! I need this to stop for my script to work correctly.

Any idea or suggestions? Thank you very much!

Comment: Sure thing! - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740268/test-php-carve-for-jpg-files

Answer (score 2):

Don't use string functions for binary data. Take a look at the [unpack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) function.

Comment: Since his example input appears to be a screenshot taken in a hex editor, I also recommend that he check *actual* input; `unpack` is definitely a better way to do it, but it won't help if the input is bad.

Comment: Actually [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) **is** binary-safe. See the note in the manual.

Comment: Hey guys, this is what I am working on. I will look more into this tomorrow now that I have some input. Thanks for the help! I will look into unpack tomorrow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740268/test-php-carve-for-jpg-files